# Разбить строку ";0;;;;1;;;;0;;;0;;;;;;3;;" и найти значение между двумя символами ";"

Tags: java

Есть строка `String str = ";0;;;;1;;;;0;;;0;;;;;;3;;";`
Например необходимо из нее достать значение которое находиться между 4-й и 5-й `";"`, где значение может быть как `"null"` так и  `"12000,00"`, и количество символов может меняться.

Comment: Разбить, разделить - по-английски split. Вдруг это поможет?

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "1;2;3;4;;1;6;7;8;0;;;0;;;;;;3;;";
    String[] subStr;
    String delimeter = ";";
    subStr = str.split(delimeter);
    String a = null;
    for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) {
        a =subStr[i];
        System.out.println("a " + a);
        if (a.equals("")) {
            a="0";
            System.out.println("a " + a);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("a " + a );
```

Подскажите плиз почему у меня "a" не определяеться, когда между ";" ничего нету?

Нашел решение: должно быть - "a.equals("")".

Comment: **Все таки не получаеться вытянуть нормально данные между предпоследней и последней ";" .**       `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:21)`

Comment: НАшол решение `for(int i = 4; i < 5; i++) {` заменил на `for(int i = 19; i< subStr.length; i++)` {